# Extracting data from "memento database" program using the "access tokens" that obtained from it, and adding it to my website's database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have data in a table inside the **"memento database"**[Memento Database App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eujzd.png) program, and I obtained **access tokens** for this table, and I want to call them in the "backend" of my website and save them in the database of my site, The data is also updated periodically, every day at 9 am.
My website is built in node.js
Can you help me with that?!!

I don't know what to do to implement this